# How echo input value in same page?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Have a coding:

```
if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{ $loggedin="0";} else { $loggedin="1"; }
if ($loggedin=="1") { echo "<form method=\"post\">
<input type=text id=\"nameField\" name=\"nameField\" value=\"". $fgmembersite->UserFullName() ." \"/></form>"; }
```

Want to echo again the nameField likE:

```
<?php echo $nameField ?>
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Set form action to same page and echo $nameField

Comment: Actually the above code is not working....

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="the-same-page.php">

    ... your code...

    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php echo $_POST['nameField'] ?>
```

If you need it without submit, then it's client-side only action.

```
<input type="text" id="foo" 
   onchange="document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = this.value"/>

<div id="output">output will be here</div>
```

Comment: i need it without submit?

Answer (score 0):

```
<? echo $_POST['nameField']; ?>
```

This is echo Posted Value...

Answer (score 0):

Without resfreshing the page / submitting the form you need to use javascript.

Include jquery then you can do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#nameField").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#xx").text(value);
    });
});
</script>

<?php

echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="nameField" name="nameField" value="'.$fgmembersite->UserFullName().'" />
</form>';

?>

<span id="xx"></span>
```

Comment: sry typo in my code.. try it again, this code wors for me... just write into input and after write click outside the input and you will se value in span element

Comment: The input field is inside the php tag!

Comment: Please look the code that I am posted. The input is inside the php tag. And I cant take the code part from the beginning of page. Because its related to the login. Can you do the above coding inside the code that I posted?